# mvn selenium:selenese hangs in the Spring Roo Tutorial

Tags: spring, maven, selenium, spring-roo

I am working my way through the Spring Roo Tutorial and I get stuck at this point:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html#beginning-step-7

This is the Maven Command line output:

```
C:\pizza>mvn selenium:selenese
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building pizzashop 0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- selenium-maven-plugin:2.1:selenese (default-cli) @ pizzashop ---
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
14:53:20.476 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
14:53:23.026 INFO - Launching Firefox...
```

at this point my FireFox 11 browser is launched but there is now visible URL and everything just seems to hang.

Any suggestions or ideas are welcome.

Environment:
OS Windows 7
JDK 1.6
Maven 3.0.3
Firefox 11
latest spring roo downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the selenium plugin configuration in the pom.xml. Note: Out of the box ( so to speak ) Roo is going to expect firefox 3.x You can either install Firefox 3.x or you can change the configuration to use another supported browser - for example:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
            <browser>*safari</browser>
            <suite>src/main/webapp/selenium/test-suite.xhtml</suite>
            <results>${project.build.directory}/selenium.html</results>
            <startURL>http://localhost:4444/</startURL>
        </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```